# Annealed and quenched free energies

Tags: statistical-mechanics, randomness

For the systems with random fields and interactions, annealed and quenched free energies are defined:
$$
F_a = -\theta\log\left(\overline{Z}\right),\quad F_q = -\theta\ \overline{\log(Z)}.
$$
Here, overline denotes averaging over random fields and interactions. Due to the concavity of the logarithm, the following inequality holds
$$
F_a \leq F_q.
$$
In some situations, equality $F_a = F_q$ is valid in the thermodynamic limit. An example of such a situation is the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model in the paramagnetic phase. In this example, the following equality is also valid in the thermodynamic limit
$$
\overline{Z^2} = \left(\overline{Z}\right)^2\quad (*).
$$
So I have two questions about the general Ising-like model with random fields and interactions.

1. Does the inequality $\overline{Z^2} > \left(\overline{Z}\right)^2$ imply the inequality $F_q > F_a$?
2. Does the equality (*) guarantee that $F_q = F_a$ also holds?

I probably should clarify that the thermodynamic limit equality $(*)$ doesn't imply that $Z$ is not random. Eq. (*) means
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{\overline{Z^2}}{\overline{Z}^2} = 1.
$$

Comment: I think this is a really good question. As far as I know, your equality (*) implies that the limit RV of $Z / \overline{Z}$ (taking $n\to\infty$) is almost surely 1. I want to say this implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} F_g / F_a = 1$, but I think this requires that the quenched disorder is sufficiently "well-behaved" (like $\pm J$ or Gaussian spin glasses)

Comment: @PeaBrane Thank you for your comment. Can you please write the answer with references to books or articles? And what do you think about the other question? Is it possible that $F_q = F_a$ while $\overline{Z^2} > \overline{Z}^2$?

Comment: Your equality implies some version of zero variance condition of the partition function in the $n\to\infty$ limit, which implies that the partition function is almost surely constant (though it may a bit tricky to justify this in the thermodynamic limit). But I'm not sure whether the $Z$ being a.s. constant implies $F_q = F_a$, but intuitively I think this is the case if $Z$ is sufficiently "well-behaved".

Comment: I do think however that the converse is true in general. In particular, if $F_q = F_a$, then convexity of the free energy implies that $Z$ is a.s. constant, which easily implies zero-variance of $Z$, meaning that the equality $\overline{Z^2} = \overline{Z}^2$ must hold.

Comment: Regarding reference, I do not have any specific statistical mechanics articles in mind, besides the classic "Spin-glass for pedestrians" which I'm sure you've already read. They give a non-rigorous justification for $F_g = F_a$ in the paramagnetic phase, which does not directly address your question (but perhaps indirectly through some sort of replica-overlap argument when looking at $\overline{Z^2}$). More formally, I think the following math SE post may help, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990009/if-varx-0-then-is-x-a-constant

Comment: @PeaBrane Thank you very much for your attention to my questions.